# Connect laptop to Android phone to connect to Internet

Tags: wireless, android

At the moment the WiFi adapter on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop is broken. I am trying to fix this but for the moment is it possible to connect my Android phone to my laptop and use the Internet connection of my phone on my laptop?

Comment: Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/q/100980/504066 ?

Answer (score 3):

Plug the USB cable between PC and android device, on android device go to **Settings** > **More settings** > **Tethering & portable hotspot** and enable **USB Tethering**

[image: usb tethering android]